# What is meant by the highlighted lines in the below program?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

The code here is being used for creating a Student Report card project but while trying to understand we can not figure out the use of and functions of the lines below from the code.

This:

`File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(student));`

and this:

`int pos=(-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(st));`

Here is the main code:

```
File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(student));
if(st.retrollno()==n)
    {
    st.showdata();
    cout<<"\n\nPlease Enter The New Details of student"<<endl;
        st.getdata();
            int pos=(-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(st));
            File.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
            File.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(student));
            cout<<"\n\n\t Record Updated";
            found=true;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C++, why use static\_cast<int>(x) instead of (int)x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx)

Comment: Do you know about [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) and [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and what they do? Do you know what arguments [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) accepts? Do you know what [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) does? Then yu know all you need to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does reinterpret\_cast<char \*>(&st) and (-1)\*static\_cast<int> mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319180/what-does-reinterpret-castchar-st-and-1static-castint-mean)

Comment: Are you two studying the same course in the same class? Those two question matchs exactly with each other? That two questions only differs by a typo!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
int pos=(-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(st));
```

converts the `unsigned int` type to integer and negates it, in order to compute the offset to seek backwards to in the next line

```
reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st)
```

just converts the pointer on the structure to a pointer on `char` so it's compatible with the function prototype. But the same pointer value is passed to the function.

So this code rewinds `sizeof(st)` bytes from the file and writes the new structure, updating the old one.

Comment: Calling a `static_cast` "overkill" and recommending a C-cast instead is pretty much backwards...

Comment: right, in theory. But a lot of C++ programs do that when there's no risk. Edited.